# Differential form calulations

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, tensors

How can we show that if we have some symmetric $(2,0)$-tensor on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}:$
$$g=\sum_{\mu,\lambda}^{2n}g_{\mu,\lambda}dx^{\mu}\otimes dx^{\lambda}$$ and $g$ satisfies $g(TX,TY)=g(X,Y)$, where $X$ and $Y$ represent any tangent vectors in the tangent space $T\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and $T$ being a $(1,1)$-tensor on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ such that:
$$T\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\bigg)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i+n}}, T\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i+n}}\bigg)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$$

> Then if $\alpha$ is a closed two-form, prove that for any $i,j,k=1,2,...,n$:
>   $$\frac{\partial g_{i,j}}{\partial x_j}-\frac{\partial g_{i,k}}{\partial x_k}=\frac{\partial g_{k,j+n}}{\partial x_{i+n}}$$

**HINT**:Define $\alpha$ to be a $(2,0)-$tensor such that $\alpha (X,Y)=g(X,TY)$ for any tangent vectors $X,Y$ and notice that we can show $\alpha$ is a $2-$form such that $\alpha(X,Y)=-\alpha(Y,X)$. Finally also express $\alpha$ as a sum of wedge products of $dx^i$'s and $dx^{j+n}$'s.

I have no idea how to begin this problem, can someone give me some hints?

Comment: What is the role of $\alpha$ in all of this?

Comment: Oo I forgot to add the hint, I will edit the post.

Comment: One question: You say that $g(TX,TY)=g(X,Y)$ but the hint says that you should define $\alpha(X,Y)=g(X,TY)$. It seems me a little strange. Are you sure it is correct, aren't you? I mean, it is not a typo.

Comment: Honestly I just copied the exact thing written in the challenging problems pdf my professor gave us for final prep. He is going to give us the solutions sometime next week but I was just eager to solve it and hence was seeking help here. Actually I have solved it half way (I hope at least), but seem to be alittle stuck, I will upload my workings soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is interesting to see that your professor gave you a final prep problem that is almost similar to a take-home midterm problem that I gave to my students in the "Calculus on Manifolds" course last year -- even the symbols used are almost the same.

I am afraid that your question above is not properly stated. The 2-form $\alpha$ should be defined in the question (before ``if $\alpha$ is closed'') rather than in the hint (that's super strange to formulate the question this way). I hope it is not your professor's fault.

For the complete question, you may visit my website
https://piazza.com/ust.hk/spring2017/math4033/resources

You can find the above question in the "Midterm" area. It was Q1 of my last year's midterm. I have also posted the solution there.

I have also observed that you asked a number of questions very similar to homework, exams, and lecture notes of my course (both last year and this year). Some crucial conditions were, however, not well stated in your posts. I hope it's not the fault of your professor. For complete version of those questions, you may visit my last year's website (link above) or this year's one:

https://canvas.ust.hk/courses/16957

Comment: Ok now I am starting to think that he is using materials as the lecture source assuming these are originally from you? Thanks for the sources, will really help me study for my upcoming finals next week :).

Comment: You are welcome. When I saw the question I thought it must be from a student from my course, but on a second thought I don't think any of my students would be so idiotic to ask questions that they can find the solutions I wrote (and ask improperly), especially my final exam has passed and grades are out.

Comment: Furthermore, I think the question was typed or stated wrongly too. The left should be $\frac{\partial g_{i,j}}{\partial x_k} - \frac{\partial g_{i,k}}{\partial x_j}$. You better ask your professor to clarify.

Comment: Ok yes I should email my professor, his pdf file suggested the problem was indeed how I wrote for this post. Now I am getting confused...